# Does Zuul supports OAuth Authentication?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

From Zuul's [wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki) I could see it can help us to perform Authentication & Security. I wanted to understand if the authentication supports OAuth or my understanding towards the Authentication is different from what they claim as Authentication.

If, it can support Authentication is there any samples from where I can look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/springbox-cloud

It is a great sample for this. Zuul serves as an api-gateway and handles authentication. The actual sample uses a fair bit of external resources if you want to start it, but the code shows what you need.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me.